# Final all $x$ such that $|\sqrt{x} - x| < 1$ (simple but can’t resolve)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I’m a beginner so be kind with me, I tried to resolve this for 2 hours now but always give me the same wrong result. I think I’m missing something big...

Can someone help me with this?

I began by assuming $x\geq 0$ (root) and then I started to make 2 systems, one with the argument $(\sqrt{x} - x) \geq 0$ and the other with the argument $<0$.
Once the systems are resolved I find a different result...

The result given by the textbook is $0\leq x<\frac{3 + \sqrt5}{2}$

Comment: I added some details, don’t know why that happens? And why the -1 btw?

Comment: Reading your explanation, it seems like you already got @coreyman317's result. Then you have to understand that this double-inequality means that both equations
$$
-1 < \sqrt{x} -x
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{x} -x <1
$$
have to be true. Of course these give different results. Then you just have to solve them one by one and you will have the range(s) of values for $x$.

Comment: Welcome to Maths Stack Exchange by the way. And you are right; -1 without an explanation is an unkind act. Take no notice.

Comment: Added the result given by the result.

Comment: by the textbook* (can’t edit the comment...)

Comment: @coreyman317 just a doubt... what if the question concerns not only to the principal square root (the positive one) $+\sqrt{x}$ but also to the negative one $-\sqrt{x}$? because $\sqrt{x}$ has two solutions, positive and negative. Although usually it is understood that it refers only to the principal root (besides in this case the question is stated by the OP as a beginner question) the fact that the expression plays with absolute values makes me wonder if the answer could be trickier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the other $2$ solutions have minor problems with them, so here is mine:

Let $\sqrt{x}=a\geq 0$. The inequality then becomes

$$|a-a^2|<1.$$

Square both sides (by non-negativity) to get
$$(a-a^2)^2<1$$

$$(a-a^2-1)(a-a^2+1)<0$$

which has solutions when $$-a^2+a-1<0, -a^2+a+1>0$$

or when $$-a^2+a-1>0, -a^2+a+1<0.$$

The first one has solutions $a\in \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}, \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$ while the second one has no real solutions.

Taking into account that $a\geq 0$ we have that $a \in \left[0,\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$.

Square this to get $x \in \left[0,\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: it must be $$x\geq 0$$ so we get two cases:

$$\sqrt{x}\geq x$$ or by squaring

$$x(x-1)\le 0$$ this is only possible for $$0\le x\le 1$$ and we get

$$\sqrt{x}<x<1$$ and by squaring
$$0<x^2+x+1$$ which is true.
So we get

$$0\le x\le 1$$
the second case is for you!

Comment: I added the result given by the textbook, already did what you said, but thanks a lot anyway it will be helpful for others :)

Answer (score 0):

For $x\geq 0$ you have that

$|x-\sqrt{x}|=|(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}|<1$ if and only if

$-\frac{3}{4}<(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2})^2<1+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{4}$

So

$-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} <\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2}<\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$

and

$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} <\sqrt{x}<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$

$0\leq x<(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2})^2=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Comment: Just one thing, the function $\sqrt{x}$ is only defined for $x\geq 0$ so you have to add this.

Comment: Thanks you, you have a reason

Comment: Your second line is wrong

Comment: I agree @asdf It should be $<1+\frac{1}{4}$ (and greater than $\frac{3}{4}$).

Comment: How you came up with the second line? “ $x>=0$ you have that... ” why? (sorry for asking as i said I’m not that good)

Comment: @neilpare2 The second line is just a calculation. I mean open the brackets in $(\sqrt(x)-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4})$

Comment: Now I think it is right

Comment: @FedericoFallucca yup now it’s right, but still I can’t understand the second line, can you explain how you came up with that? (if you want to, thanks)

Comment: |y-1/4|<1 implies -1+1/4 <y<1+1/4 andò now you can choose y=(\sqrt(x)-1/2)^2

Answer (score 0):

Of course, we must immediately have that $x\ge 0$ since otherwise, we would be saying that the field of complex numbers is ordered, which it is not.

Now under that assumption we have that $\sqrt x-x<1$ or $\sqrt x-x>-1.$

The first inequality gives $\sqrt x<1+x.$ Clearly, $x+1>0$ for all $x\ge0,$ and with the convention that $\sqrt x\ge0$ we can square both sides of the inequality $\sqrt x<1+x$ and rearrange to obtain $x^2+x+1>0,$ which is clearly true for all $x\ge 0.$

The second inequality $\sqrt x-x>-1$ gives $\sqrt x>x-1.$ Now, it is clear that $x-1>0$ whenever $x>1,$ so that we can square both sides and rearrange again to obtain $x^2-3x+1<0$ which gives $$\left(x-\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}\right)<0.$$ Therefore, it follows that either $$0\le x<\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2} \tag{*}$$ or $$x>\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}. \tag{**}$$ On the other hand whenever $x\in[0,1],$ it is clear that $\sqrt x>x-1$ is satisfied since then $x-1<0$ (again on the convention that $\sqrt x\ge0$). Combining the inequality $0\le x\le 1$ with $(*)$ and $(**)$, we obtain $(*)$ since $(**)$ and $[0,1]$ intersect in $\varnothing.\blacksquare$

Comment: Amazing answer! Thanks a lot! This is really helpful :)

Comment: @neilpare2 I am glad for the feedback.